# Adapter,progress dialog doesn't work in fragment

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, android-adapter, android-progressbar

I have class that extend fragment

```
public class  oUnit  extends Fragment {
```

I want to fill list and add it to linear layout so I use the following code

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                 ProgressDialog connectionProgressDialog = new 

ProgressDialog( getActivity());
          connectionProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
          connectionProgressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
          connectionProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
          connectionProgressDialog.setMessage("Uploading Leads...");
          connectionProgressDialog.show();

         View view = inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.chemounit,
                    container,
                    false);


        //Intialize the record Grid
         LinearLayout formLayout = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.UnitGrid);
        formLayout.removeAllViews();

        MainGrid = new ListView(getActivity().getApplicationContext());              
        MainGrid.setVisibility(ListView.VISIBLE);
         LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                 LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
         params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
         MainGrid.setLayoutParams(params);


         //2. Call the web Service 



         GlobalVariables appState = (GlobalVariables) getActivity().getApplication();

         Log.d(" in Chemo unit"," the array is has "+  appState.encounters.size());

         MainGrid.setAdapter(new Encounteradapter(view.getContext(),R.id.ChemoUnitGrid ,  appState.encounters));
        // Finally add it 

         formLayout.addView(MainGrid);


       connectionProgressDialog.dismiss();

     return view;
    }
```

I am sure that the global variable list is not null and contains data (I used `log.d`  to display its length) ,, the Adapter class is like

```
public class Encounteradapter   extends ArrayAdapter<Encounter> {

    private final Context context;

    TextView textViewTime ;
    TextView textViewPatientName;
    Button ButottonArrive ;
    Button ButottonEncounter;
    Button ButottonExit; 
    ArrayList<Encounter> Encounters ; 

    public Encounteradapter(Context context, int  ResourceId,
            ArrayList<Encounter> items)
    {


        super(context, ResourceId, items);
        this.context = context;
         this.Encounters = items ; 
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chemounitgrid, parent, false);




        Encounter EncounterObject = Encounters.get(position);

         textViewTime = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.Time);
        textViewTime.setText(EncounterObject.bookingDate);

        textViewPatientName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.Time);
        textViewPatientName.setText(EncounterObject.Name);

        ButottonArrive = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.test1);
        ButottonEncounter = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.test2);
        ButottonExit = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.test3);

        rowView.setTag(position);




        return rowView;
    }
}
```

but nothing appear the list doesn't appear, I also tried to remopve the section of properties I set but nothing either

this is the first issue the second I try to display progress on fragment OnCreate() but it doesn't appear I use the following code

```
  connectionProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
  connectionProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
  connectionProgressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
  connectionProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
  connectionProgressDialog.setMessage("Uploading Leads...");
  connectionProgressDialog.show();
```

any idea how to fix that , do I miss anything in with fragment

Comment: That `ProgressDialog` should work. Are you using the `ActionBarSherlock` library?

Comment: I don't know what could be causing the `ProgressDialog` to not appear. I've tested your `ProgressDialog` code and it works with no problems.

Comment: Yes, I tried it both in the `onCreate` method of a `Fragment` and in the `onCreateView` method of the `Fragment`. In both cases the `ProgressDialog` appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's normal that you don't have anything on the screen because in the `onCreateView` method you inflate the layout and setup the `ListView` but then when it's time to return the view(the layout for that fragment with the `ListView` where you put the data) you do:

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.chemounit, container, false);
```

which will inflate again the layout file with a empty `ListView`(so all the setup that you previously done was useless as you discarded the first inflated `View`). Instead you should return:

```
return view;
```

Comment: what about the progress dialoge , also any more details about ur expplanation

Comment: @AMH That `ProgressDialog` as you declared it should work with no problems. Maybe there is something wrong in particular in your code so you should add the full code for the fragment where you try to use it. I don't know what extra explanation to give you about the missing `ListView`. Just return the first inflated `View` and not what you're currently returning because that will give another empty view and you don't want that.

Comment: the return view ,worked will and displayed the list , but the progress doesn't appear , see my updated code

Comment: @Luksprog , when i am doing ProgressDialog connectionProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity()) , in a fragment it is displayed in the whole Activity , not in a particular fragment .

Comment: @TusharPandey That's a normal dialog behavior. If you want to only show the progress for that fragment only then use an inline `ProgressBar` widget.

Answer (score 4):

### in onCreateView try this

```
View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.chemounit, container, false);
  ProgressDialog connectionProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
  connectionProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
  connectionProgressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
  connectionProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
  connectionProgressDialog.setMessage("Uploading Leads...");
 connectionProgressDialog.show();
 return view;
```